# Setting an active menu item based on the current URL with jQuery

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I want to active menu item on the current URL , now its my HTML :

```
<ul class="header-tools nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="mysetting">  
        <a class="link-menu-active" href="">first title</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mysetting">
        <a class="link-menu-active" href="">second title</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mysetting">
        <a class="link-menu-active" href="">third title</a>                                     
    </li>   
</ul>
```

and it's my jquery code :

```
$(".header-tools.nav.navbar-nav li").each(function() {
    var navItem = $(this);
    if( $(navItem).find("a").attr("href") == location.href ) {
         navItem.addClass("active");
    }
});
```

or it :

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
path = decodeURIComponent(path);

$(".header-tools.nav.navbar-nav li a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

but none of them doesn't work , what should I do ?

So Thanks

Comment: have you tried console.log for your path and href values to see what is being compared and skipped?

Comment: Why do you want to do this client-side? Wordpress already has functionality to give the current menu item (and its parents, if any) specific classes - why can’t you use those? (And what does tag `recaptcha` have to do with this?)

Answer (score 0):

For this exact use case, you can check if the current path matches or contains the anchor href and act accordingly.

```
$('.mysetting').each(function() {
    var path = window.location.pathname,
        href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
        exactMatch = (path === href), // URL is the same as anchor. Useful when your path can contain the href of multiple links
        closeMatch = (path.indexOf(href) !== -1);   // URL contains anchor. 
                                                    // Useful when you don't know if query strings and other crap will be appended/prepended to your links

    if (exactMatch /* or closeMatch depending on your preference*/) {

        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
})
```

Although, as already noted in the comments above, WP has built-in nav functions that handle exactly this kind of situation and are a lot more robust than any few lines of javascript you can come up with.